# Fragment Transition with onBackPressed()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, onbackpressed

I am working on fragment transaction, and the backstack is like this:

> fragA => fragB => fragC => fragD

I would like to return to fragA after back from the fragD based on success state:

> fragD => onBackPressed() => fragA

without removing fragB and fragC from back stack

How can I do this with `Fragment`s and also with `Activity`s?

Answer (score 1):

When adding the fragment to backstack you have to specify the name like this:

```
transaction.addToBackStack(fragment_home.getClass().getName());
```

When popping it from stack you can try either by using fragment name or by position.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack("Name of the Fragment",
                                         FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

By this way you can traverse any fragment from the stack

You can also try it inside `onBackPressed()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with fragments (at least not to my knowledge).

But to answer the second part of your question (how to do that with activities)...You can achieve that affect with a SingleTask activity.  Set Activity A as singleTask in your Manifest file and when it launches, rather than creating a new instance, it will reopen the old instance.  Per Android's documentation, when launching a SingleTask Activity...

> The system creates the activity at the root of a new task and routes the intent to it. However, if an instance of the activity already exists, the system routes the intent to existing instance through a call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new one.

So you simply override onNewIntent() in Activity A, and in essence, when it gets called from Activity D, it will be pulled back up to the top of the stack, while B and C will remain on the stack below it.

Check out this link for more info.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html